# error building opengl shader in ubuntu

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, shader, glew

I am trying to build the oglpg-8th-edition under Ubuntu. I have set the linker and included the header folder as follows:

g++ -L/home/maki/Downloads/oglpg-8th-edition/lib -o "test5"  ./LoadShaders.o ./source.o   -lglew32 -lfreeglut

When I build it using eclipse I get:

./LoadShaders.o: In function `LoadShaders':
/home/bkk/workspace/test5/Debug/../LoadShaders.cpp:59: undefined reference to`_*glewCreateProgram'
/home/bkk/workspace/test5/Debug/../LoadShaders.cpp:63: undefined reference to `__glewCreateShader'
/home/bkk/workspace/test5/Debug/../LoadShaders.cpp:70: undefined reference to`*_glewDeleteShader'
/home/bkk/workspace/test5/Debug/../LoadShaders.cpp:77: undefined reference to `__glewShaderSource'
/home/bkk/workspace/test5/Debug/../LoadShaders.cpp:80: undefined reference to`_*glewCompileShader'
/home/bkk/workspace/test5/Debug/../LoadShaders.cpp:83: undefined reference to `__glewGetShaderiv'
/home/bkk/workspace/test5/Debug/../LoadShaders.cpp:98: undefined reference to`*_glewAttachShader'
/home/bkk/workspace/test5/Debug/../LoadShaders.cpp:109: undefined reference to `__glewLinkProgram'
/home/bkk/workspace/test5/Debug/../LoadShaders.cpp:112: undefined reference to`_*glewGetProgramiv'
/home/bkk/workspace/test5/Debug/../LoadShaders.cpp:125: undefined reference to `*_glewDeleteShader'

I also think all the packages installed. Any ideas where might I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, the library you link against is called `libGLEW`. Your distribution may have this library in binary form for Linux, though it is not officially distributed this way. When you build the library for Linux, it should output: `libGLEW.so`.

Thus your Makefile should be using `-lGLEW` instead of `-lglew32` (this is for MinGW / Cygwin).